# Does the Java platform replace all remote objects with their stubs during a remote method invocation?

Tags: java, networking, rmi

Does the Java platform replace all remote objects with their `stub`s during a remote method invocation?  During `RMI` we know that, `JVM` creates a `stub` methods for calling and caller methods, my question is that, after function get called then the then communication happens between stubs through networking sockets, so that at the time returning result to the remote object, is that all remote objects are replaced by their stubs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the Java platform replace all remote objects with their stubs during a remote method invocation?

All *exported* remote objects, yes, during marshaling of the arguments or result objects.

> During RMI we know that, JVM creates a stub methods for calling and caller methods

Not exactly. RMI creates the stub object for a remote object when the object is exported.

> my question is that, after function get called then the then communication happens between stubs through networking sockets

No. It happens between the stub at the client and the RMI runtime system at the server.

> so that at the time returning result to the remote object, is that all remote objects are replaced by their stubs?

Now that is correct, but not for the reason you gave.